# Twig node visitor priority from -10 to 10 - what will be executed first, what last?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Twig node interface defines getPriority. Doc block comments says that value should be between -10 and 10, default is 0.

What priority is executed first, what last? That is not documented at all...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/NodeTraverser.php#L61) you'll see that the visitors are sorted by **ascending** order, and then called. So **Lower** Priority gets called sooner.

Comment: Ok, now you made me look like extremely lazy and stupid... :( but thank you! That is correct answer :)